# On SQL Server 2008, how to find out when was any database offline/online?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have to include one report in my application showing offline/online activity of few databases on SQL Server 2008.
Could you please suggest how can I collect the same information from sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find out when your database was taken OFFLINE, you can use the SQL [that I posted before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2447464/1501497), or the easiest way is to check the Event Viewer and it will tell you when the Database was taken OFFLINE.  I have just tested this on my local machine and SQL Server writes out an Information message to the Application log.

Comment: @Neil to which SQL do you refer?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use below query to check database status.

```
SELECT Name, state_desc FROM sys.databases
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('YOURDATABASE', 'Status')
DatabaseStatus_DATABASEPROPERTYEX
GO

SELECT state_desc DatabaseStatus_sysDatabase
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = 'YOURDATABASE'
GO
```

This will tell you the status of the database.

Comment: Using these queries I can find out if the database is offline/online at present. However, I am looking for a way to know the time when the database went online /offline last time.